# Access recursive attributes in custom ASP.NET Core TagHelper to modify their HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I made a custom ASP.NET Core TagHelper which adds validation for parsley based on DataAnnotations-Attributes. As an example, the `[Required]` attribute will result in `required=""` for an input field. This works fine, but only on the first level of propertys. But I also need to validate custom attributes on child entitys.

A short example:

```
public class ModelA{
    [Required]
    public string Test{get;set;}
    public ModelB ModelB{get;set;}
}

public class ModelB{
    [Required]
    public string AnotherTest{get;set;}
}
```

When I access the property of Model A like `<input asp-for="Test" />` it works fine, but the child entity like `<input asp-for="ModelB.AnotherTest" />` doesn't fire my `Process` method of the TagHelper

```
public class MyValidator:InputTagHelper{
    [HtmlAttributeName("parsley-validation")]
    public bool ParsleyValidation { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output){
        if(ParsleyValidation){
              output.Attributes.Add("required", null);
        }
    }
}
```

Using reflection is not working here because I need the `TagHelperOutput` instance of the attribute. But I didn't get this when I loop through the propertys of the child class myself using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: I did a logical mistake. In the `Process` method, I looped through every attribute of my model. This doesn't really make sense because this method is fired for every attribute. And this loop cause trouble for the `TagHelperOutput`: The instance is only for the current attribute. So when I loop through them, the method is called for attribute X, when I do something for attribute Y.

Of course, ASP.NET Core will fire the `Process` method also for child-entitys. In my case, the `parsley-validation` was missing in the child-entity. As a result, my code was nevery executed (if statement). Stupid mistakes, but now everything works and make sense. The question is obsolet because the TagHelper are working correctly when you know how to use them right.